# Writing PostgreSQL database credentials in Vault ends up with connection refused

Tags: postgresql, docker, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to learn on how to implement Vault using Docker and PostgreSQL.
The goal is to create a docker container with PostgreSQL and connect to it using HashiCorp Vault.
I managed to create a yml file with the configuration of docker, postgresql and vault.

```
    version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgreSQLCon
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
    ports:
      - 5432:5432 #important to configure vault with postgreSQL


  adminer:
    image: adminer
    container_name: adminerCon
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080


  vault:
      image: vault:latest
      container_name: vaultCon
      depends_on:
        - "db"
      volumes:
         - ./vault/config:/vault/config
         - ./vault/policies:/vault/policies
         - ./vault/data:/vault/data
         - ./vault/logs:/vault/logs
      ports:
        - 8200:8200
      environment:
        - VAULT_ADDR=http://127.0.0.1:8200
      cap_add:
        - IPC_LOCK
      command: ['vault', 'server', '-config=/vault/config/vault-config.json']
```

**vault-config.json**

```
{
  "backend": {
    "file": {
      "path": "vault/data"
    }
  },
  "listener": {
    "tcp":{
      "address": "0.0.0.0:8200",
      "tls_disable": 1
    }
  },
  "ui": true
}
```

When the vault is up, I'm connecting to the container using docker exec -it. I manage to unseal and login into vault. When I'm running the followed command:

```
vault write database/config/my-postgresql-database \
    plugin_name=postgresql-database-plugin \
    allowed_roles="my-role" \
    connection_url="postgresql://{{username}}:{{password}}@localhost:5432/?sslmode=disable" \
    username="admin" \
    password="example"
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error writing data to database/config/my-postgresql-database: Error making API request.

URL: PUT http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/database/config/my-postgresql-database
Code: 400. Errors:

* error creating database object: error verifying connection: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you need to connect to the DB container using its container IP address, not `127.0.0.1`. This should be discoverable using the container name (`db`), so just replace `localhost` in your connection URL with `db`:

```
vault write database/config/my-postgresql-database \
    plugin_name=postgresql-database-plugin \
    allowed_roles="my-role" \
    connection_url="postgresql://{{username}}:{{password}}@db:5432/?sslmode=disable" \
    username="admin" \
    password="example"
```

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ .

Comment: Thank you, did not realized that you need to change the connection to the container and not localhost.